Did early church fathers accept or deny real presence?
They all have some quotes which seem to support it and others which seem to deny it. Here are just a few.

Then, having taken the bread and given it to His disciples, He made it His own body, by saying, “This is my body,” that is, the figure of my body. A figure, however, there could not have been, unless there were first a veritable body.

This seems like it could be interpreted a number of ways...but if it was solely just a metaphor, why would Jesus "make it" his body? If it's not actually his body, what is he "making it"?

Now, because they thought His discourse was harsh and intolerable, supposing that He had really and literally enjoined on them to eat his flesh, He, with the view of ordering the state of salvation as a spiritual thing, set out with the principle, “It is the spirit that quickens;” and then added, “The flesh profits nothing,”— meaning, of course, to the giving of life. He also goes on to explain what He would have us to understand by spirit

The way this is phrased makes it seem like it's not literally Christ's flesh.
Iraneus says something similar:

For when the Greeks, having arrested the slaves of Christian catechumens, then used force against them, in order to learn from them some secret thing [practised] among Christians, these slaves, having nothing to say that would meet the wishes of their tormentors, except that they had heard from their masters that the divine communion was the body and blood of Christ, and imagining that it was actually flesh and blood, gave their inquisitors answer to that effect.


Will it do to give quotes without saying who the claimed 'Church Father' was, the document quoted from, or a rough idea of the date? The first 2 examples given lack all those points. Even the 3rd only gives a name but no date or document reference.  Will it be okay to suppose the 'pool' dates from the end of the 1st century to John Damascene (in the East) 750, or Gregory the Great (in the West) 604? Mind you, others claim candidates such as  the Venerable Bede in 735. Do we not need more specifics, to avoid picking and choosing to suit a preferred stance? Otherwise this is all just too general

Can you state who said the first two quotes and where?

Your question is ambiguous. The real presence of what?  Do you mean they real, physical body of Christ in the bread he broke on the night he was betrayed, before he died?

You should remove the catholic tag... You're talking about the early church.

@Lesley I believe "Real Presence" is the fundamental belief of the eucharist as nonsymbolic. Does not seem ambiguous at all to me. The quotes and format are awful though.

@Anne I know it's a crazy wide range (I would end with Augustine, personally) , but I think we use the tag wiki from [tag:church-fathers] unless someone specifically limits, we go up to the 7th century

@PeterTurner  Indeed, a wide range. I will leave answers up to those conversant with so many learned gentlemen. P.S. Were there any learned ladies counted as Church Mothers?

@Anne yeah, there are some extant writings of the Desert Mothers which are pretty good.  But most of the great ladies of that time were martyrs.  Although I think St. Catherine of Alexandria might be considered both.

@PeterTurner  Interesting; thanks

Does "corpus suum illum fecit", the original Latin for "He made it His own body" require the English meaning of literally creating or transforming? See Latin, page 492 and English, page 493.

@Anne
https://ccel.org/ccel/irenaeus/fragments_of_the_lost_writings_of_irenaeus/anf01.ix.viii.xiii.html from Irenaeus regarding the martyrs of Lyons, always to be remembered.

I am answering with early church fathers... these are a mixture of Orthodox and Catholic ones (and origen)


“We will necessarily add this also. Proclaiming the death, according to the flesh, of the only-begotten Son of God, that is Jesus Christ, confessing his resurrection from the dead, and his ascension into heaven, we offer the unbloody sacrifice in the churches, and so go on to the mystical thanksgivings, and are sanctified, having received his holy flesh and the precious blood of Christ the Savior of us all. And not as common flesh do we receive it; God forbid: nor as of a man sanctified and associated with the Word according to the unity of worth, or as having a divine indwelling, but as truly the life-giving and very flesh of the Word himself. For he is the life according to his nature as God, and when he became united to his flesh, he made it also to be life-giving” (Session 1, Letter of Cyril to Nestorius [A.D. 431]).  - Council of Ephesus


“Christ was carried in his own hands when, referring to his own body, he said, ‘This is my body’ [Matt. 26:26]. For he carried that body in his hands” (Explanations of the Psalms 33:1:10 [A.D. 405]).
“I promised you [new Christians], who have now been baptized, a sermon in which I would explain the sacrament of the Lord’s Table. . . . That bread which you see on the altar, having been sanctified by the word of God, is the body of Christ. That chalice, or rather, what is in that chalice, having been sanctified by the word of God, is the blood of Christ” (Sermons 227 [A.D. 411]).
…
“What you see is the bread and the chalice; that is what your own eyes report to you. But what your faith obliges you to accept is that the bread is the body of Christ and the chalice is the blood of Christ. This has been said very briefly, which may perhaps be sufficient for faith; yet faith does not desire instruction” (ibid., 272).  (Augustine)


“I have no taste for corruptible food nor for the pleasures of this life. I desire the bread of God, which is the flesh of Jesus Christ, who was of the seed of David; and for drink I desire his blood, which is love incorruptible” (Letter to the Romans 7:3 [A.D. 110]).
“Take note of those who hold heterodox opinions on the grace of Jesus Christ which has come to us, and see how contrary their opinions are to the mind of God. . . . They abstain from the Eucharist and from prayer because they do not confess that the Eucharist is the flesh of our Savior Jesus Christ, flesh which suffered for our sins and which that Father, in his goodness, raised up again. They who deny the gift of God are perishing in their disputes” (Letter to the Smyrnaeans 6:2–7:1 [A.D. 110]). - St. Ignatius of Antioch


“We call this food Eucharist, and no one else is permitted to partake of it, except one who believes our teaching to be true and who has been washed in the washing which is for the remission of sins and for regeneration [i.e., has received baptism] and is thereby living as Christ enjoined. For not as common bread nor common drink do we receive these; but since Jesus Christ our Savior was made incarnate by the word of God and had both flesh and blood for our salvation, so too, as we have been taught, the food which has been made into the Eucharist by the Eucharistic prayer set down by him, and by the change of which our blood and flesh is nurtured, is both the flesh and the blood of that incarnated Jesus” (First Apology 66 [A.D. 151]). - St. Justin Martyr


“’Eat my flesh,’ [Jesus] says, ‘and drink my blood.’ The Lord supplies us with these intimate nutrients, he delivers over his flesh and pours out his blood, and nothing is lacking for the growth of his children” (The Instructor of Children 1:6:43:3 [A.D. 191]). -St. Clement of Alexandria


“Formerly there was baptism in an obscure way . . . now, however, in full view, there is regeneration in water and in the Holy Spirit. Formerly, in an obscure way, there was manna for food; now, however, in full view, there is the true food, the flesh of the Word of God, as he himself says: ‘My flesh is true food, and my blood is true drink’ [John 6:55]” (Homilies on Numbers 7:2 [A.D. 248]).
“I wish to admonish you with examples from your religion. You are accustomed to take part in the divine mysteries, so you know how, when you have received the Body of the Lord, you reverently exercise every care lest a particle of it fall and lest anything of the consecrated gift perish. You account yourselves guilty, and rightly do you so believe, if any of it be lost through negligence.” (Homilies on Exodus 13:3 [A.D. 244]) -Origen


The early church believed in the real presence of Christ in the sacrament of communion.
